# How to reach content in QTreeWidget second colum QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox, qtreewidget

I have an `AppDialog(QtGui.QWidget)` containing a `QtreeWidget`.

`self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget()`

I populate data from `self.sequences` to this QtreeWidget with the function `seqTree`.

Datas from `self.sequences`:

```
{'090': 
  {'090-0010': [
    {'code': '090-0010_v000', 'type': 'Version', 'id': 26676, 'entity.Shot.sg_sequence.Sequence.code': '090', 'entity.Shot.code': '090-0010'}, 
    {'code': '090-0010_maquette_v001', 'type': 'Version', 'id': 27848, 'entity.Shot.sg_sequence.Sequence.code': '090', 'entity.Shot.code': '090-0010'}, 
    {'code': '090-0010_maquette_v002', 'type': 'Version', 'id': 27849, 'entity.Shot.sg_sequence.Sequence.code': '090', 'entity.Shot.code': '090-0010'}]}, 
'082': 
  {'082-0020': [
    {'code': '082-0020_compo_v000', 'type': 'Version', 'id': 28748, 'entity.Shot.sg_sequence.Sequence.code': '082', 'entity.Shot.code': '082-0020'}}
```

Function `seqTree`:

```
def seqTree(self):  
    for seq in sorted(self.sequences):
        if self.sequences[seq]:
            parent = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
            parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsTristate | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            parent.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            parent.setText(0,unicode(seq))
            for shot in self.sequences[seq]:
                child = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
                child.setFlags(child.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                child.setCheckState(0, QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
                child.setText(0,unicode(shot))
                versionCombo = QtGui.QComboBox(self.tree)
                versionCombo.setFixedWidth(200)
                for version in sorted(self.sequences[seq][shot], reverse=True):
                    versionCombo.addItem(version['code'])
                self.tree.setItemWidget(child, 1, versionCombo)
```

This solution works to populate datas.  My QTreeWidget is structure by first keys, then as child, second keys in the first column. In the second column, I add a `QComboBox` with the content from code, for exemple '090-0010_maquette_v001'.

But then, I'm unable to retrieve content of the ComboBox. 
To retrieve the selection, I use the following function:

```
def checkedList(self):
    checked = dict()
    self.selection = []
    root = self.tree.invisibleRootItem()
    signal_count = root.childCount()

    for i in range(signal_count):
        signal = root.child(i)
        checked_sweeps = list()
        num_children = signal.childCount()

        for n in range(num_children):
            child = signal.child(n)
            if child.checkState(0) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                checked_sweeps.append(child.text(0))
                #### I need here to retrieve the content of ComboBox.

        checked[signal.text(0)] = checked_sweeps

    for item in sorted(checked):
        if not checked[item] == []:
            for shot in checked[item]: 
                self.selection.append(shot)
```

I really can't find how to reach the second column of `child`. I've tried multiple things like `child.data()`, `indexFromItem()`. Do I need to link the ComboBox to the class to be able to find it? or the link to the QtreeWidget is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the `QComboBox` with `itemWidget`:

```
if child.checkState(0) == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
    checked_sweeps.append(child.text(0))
    combo = self.tree.itemWidget(child, 1)
    print(combo.currentText())
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks.